# MVC ADO without using EF

Tags: stored-procedures, razor, model-view-controller, ado.net

i wonder how to implement M-V-C ADO without using EF.
just like a pure ADO implementation. any suggestions and sample are appreciated Thanks guys.

Comment: Sorry, just must be mistaking this website for google. Suggested google search terms: "mvc without entity framework"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ADO.NET connections haven't really changed at all with MVC coming around. They still rely on things like [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) objects and their associated commands.

If you wanted to build a simply query, it might look like the following :

```
// Build your connection
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("{your-connection-string-here"}))
{
     // Build your query
     var query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE foo = @bar";
     // Create a command to execute your query
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
     {
          // Open the connection
          connection.Open();
          // Add any parameters if necessary
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", 42);

          // Execute your query here (in this case using a data reader)
          using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
                // Iterate through your results
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                      // The current reader object will contain each row here, so you
                      // can access the values as expected
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: i will locate this ADO on the Models section , right ?

Comment: This really depends on your own style or preferences. You would likely either perform this in your controller to access the data you need (or further abstract it into its own class like a data access layer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type of ADO commands and paramaterized SQL seen here to retrieve data:

```
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, desc FROM mytable WHERE id = @id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", myid);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new myItem
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id")),
                Desc = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("desc")),
            }
        }
```

There are lot of examples on MSDN for CRUD.